# Website running slow in IE

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

A website that I am working on is loading slow in IE for certain users. It is loading OK in other browsers but not IE.

The site is http://tinyurl.com/ctzxlv8.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Thats a performance issue actually and its not possible to answer this question here because there may be so many reason for slow processing site .Sorry can't help here :-)

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with browsers is that not all run same syntax same way. Of course, there is a standard html, but each browser tries to extend syntax in order to be able to run more webs... browsers developers think: more flexibility -> more webs reproducible -> more users.
But this can be a trap for web developers when you are using just one browser to check if your web runs. For instance: I use a lot firefox, but it accepts a lot more syntax than just the standard one. It could run my code perfectly, but IExplorer could have some problems trying to understand my non standard code.

All I want to say is, check your html syntax on a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Your site has 65 Errors, 124 warning(s). Fix them to a standard code, will probably help ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've fixed the errors so we will see if this makes any difference.